# Execute @ with another Execute@

Tags: sql, sql-server, execute

How can I make this work? I want to be able to update the @result0 depending on if the variables are 0 or 1 and then put it into another set@ and then call the @result. The  ##tempz table does exist. When I run this though, it just gives me : (125 row(s) affected)

```
DECLARE @result nvarchar(max),@result0 nvarchar(max)
SET @showstore = 1
SET @showcashier = 0
SET @showregister = 0
SET @showdate = 0  

set @result = 'select '+@result0+' from ##tempz'
set @result0 = 'Amex,[Gift Card],Debit,[Off Line C.Card],[Str Cr],[House Acct],Cash,Rebate,[C.Card],VIP,Discover,[Check],MasterCard,[Visa/MC]'

If @showstore = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'StoreID,' + @result0
    end
If @showcashier = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'Cashier,' + @result0
    end
If @showregister = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'Register,' + @result0
    end
If @showdate = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'Date,' + @result0
    end
execute(@result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the value for `@result` on your last line, after all the `IF..ELSE`:

```
DECLARE @result nvarchar(max),@result0 nvarchar(max)
SET @showstore = 1
SET @showcashier = 0
SET @showregister = 0
SET @showdate = 0  

set @result0 = 'Amex,[Gift Card],Debit,[Off Line C.Card],[Str Cr],[House Acct],Cash,Rebate,[C.Card],VIP,Discover,[Check],MasterCard,[Visa/MC]'

If @showstore = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'StoreID,' + @result0
    end
If @showcashier = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'Cashier,' + @result0
    end
If @showregister = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'Register,' + @result0
    end
If @showdate = 1
    begin
        set @result0 = 'Date,' + @result0
    end
set @result = 'select '+@result0+' from ##tempz'
execute(@result)
```